# Какая кодировка при использовании файлов txt в php?

Tags: html, php

Какая требуется кодировка в txt файлах и кодировка html страниц при использовании файлов txt в php скриптах (в той же html страницы)? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы сохраняете с помощью текстового редактора от windows (блокнот), то ANSI (кодировка) самое "то". В HTML я бы по советовал использовать кодировку cp1251, хотя она уже устарела и пора переходить на utf-8, кодировка страницы указывается таким образом :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Неоднократно уже встречал здесь термин "кодировка ANSI". 

Что это ? CP-1251, CP-866 или ISO-8859-5 или где ее посмотреть ?

Comment: ANSI - кодировка в указана в блокноте, и при нажатии Ctr + S высветится окошко, где попросит ввести имя файла, а ниже и кодировку. cp1251 - кодировка для html страниц, но лучше использовать utf-8, просто впишите ещё charset=windows-1251 или charset=utf-8.

Comment: ANSI - проверил. Так эти умники в Notepad обозвали CP-1251.

Comment: Тогда пробуйте в utf-8 создавать свои html страницы, по поводу этой кодировки сказать ничего не смогу, т.к. пользуюсь cp1251.

Comment: [ANSI (значения)][1]

> В системах Microsoft Windows кодовая
> страница ANSI (англ. ANSI code page,
> ACP) может означать:
> 
>  - Windows-1252 (в контексте    американских и западноевропейских локализаций)
>  - Windows-1251 — так называемая ранее    корпорацией Microsoft «кириллица ANSI» (англ. ANSI Cyrillic)
>  - Вообще любую кодировку системы, указанную в ключе `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage\ACP`

А так, конечно-же, ANSI - это не кодировка.

  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_(%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Answer (score 3):

Кодировка должна быть та же, что и на HTML странице. Предпочтительнее везде использовать только UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

если думаете серьёзно программить, то *только* utf8!!! Не будет проблем с русскими регулярками, например. Да и вообще она международная и универсальная.

Comment: тем боле,что скоро ютф8 станет стандартом,и вообще - пора привыкать к правилам хорошего тона,конечно - можно и на Денвере чудеса творить,но ручками поставить Апач и мускул - лишь добавляет знаний и уверенности в себе.

Comment: К слову, универсальная - скорее UTF16. С ней проблема только одна - объем БД ))